# An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, asp.net-web-api, exception

I am currently working on Weather API in which I am trying to take values from OpenWeatherMap.org. But When I click the button to retrieve the information from the website. It gives me the following Error.[Here's the Screenshot of the exception,I am Getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLlOl.png)

Also Here's the UI for Button I am clicking.

[Here's the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znUAe.png)

```
System.Exception was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
Source=UWPWeather
StackTrace:
   at UWPWeather.LocationManager.<GetPosition>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at UWPWeather.MainPage.<Button_Click>d__1.MoveNext()
   InnerException:
```

The OpenWeatherMapProxy.cs code:

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Net.Http;
        using System.Runtime.Serialization;
        using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace WeatherAPI
        {
        public class OpenWeatherMapProxy
        {
        public async static Task<RootObject>GetWeather(double lat,double lon)

        {

        var http = new HttpClient();

        var response = await http.GetAsync("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? lat=35&lon=77.20081&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a");


        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));

        var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        return data;

    }

}

public class Coord
{
    [DataMember]
    public double lon { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double lat { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Weather
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string main { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Main
{
    [DataMember]
    public double temp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Wind
{
    [DataMember]
    public double speed { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int deg { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Clouds
{
    [DataMember]
    public int all { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Sys
{
    [DataMember]
    public int type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string @base { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Main main { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int dt { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

    // The Blank Page item template is documented at           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

   namespace WeatherAPI
   {
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RootObject myWeather = await OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather(20.0,30.0);
        ResultTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name + " - " + ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString();
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Please copy the full exception as TEXT into the question.

Comment: What's `LocationManager`?

Comment: It might also be useful to add the code that is responsible for the exception.  I _think_ this is because your web request is failing in an async call and you're not handling the exception, but without the code I'm guessing.

Comment: You want the c# code?

Comment: @CodingGorilla I've updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: @Wimmel Have a look please.

Comment: @MatiasCicero I've updated the whole code. Please help if you can.